# array missing elements with a subroutine thread

Tags: arrays, multithreading, perl

A simple code either to be run in a thread or without thread. When run in a thread the processing doesn't process all the elements in the array. But when run without threading then it processes all the elements.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w -I /opt/hypertable/0.9.7.3/lib/perl -I /opt/hypertable/0.9.7.3/lib/perl/gen-perl
use strict;
use IO::Socket;
use Geo::IP;
use threads qw(stringify);
use Net::NBName;
use Data::Dumper;
use Hypertable::ThriftClient;

# Syslog Variables and Constants
my $MAXLEN = 1524;
my $limit = 5; #for testing
my $sock;
# Start Listening on UDP port 514
$sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(LocalPort => '514', Proto => 'udp') || die("Socket: $@");

my $buf = '';
my $count = 0;
my @set;

for ($count = 0; $count <= $limit; $count++) {
  $sock->recv($buf, $MAXLEN);
  my ($port, $ipaddr) = sockaddr_in($sock->peername);
  my $hn = gethostbyaddr($ipaddr, AF_INET);
  $buf =~ /<(\d+)>(.*?):(.*)/;
  my $msg = $3;
  $set[$count][0] = $hn;
  $set[$count][1] = $msg;
  print $count." --> ".$set[$count][0]." --> ".$set[$count][1]."\n";#Print original array, should print 5 elements 

  my $thr = threads->create('logsys',@set);

  #&logsys(@set);
}

sub logsys {
  my $count = 0;
  my @set = @_;

  print "--------------------- ".scalar (@set)." -------------------\n";

  for ($count=0; $count <= $limit; $count++) {
    print $count." --> ".$set[$count][0]." --> ".$set[$count][1]."\n";#print passed array, should same exact 5 elements
    if (open(WW,">syslog")){
      print WW $count." --> ".$set[$count][0]." --> ".$set[$count][1]."\n"; close(WW);
    }
  }
}
```

**O/P when run as a thread:**

```
0 --> ids-01p --> 23:48 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][138:4:1] sensitive_data: sensitive data - U.S. social security numbers without dashes [Classification: Sensitive Data] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.10.97.42:3065 -> 33.87.66.38:80
1 --> ids-01p --> 23:50 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][138:4:1] sensitive_data: sensitive data - U.S. social security numbers without dashes [Classification: Sensitive Data] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.10.1.254:26616 -> 78.67.61.202:80
2 --> ids-01p --> 23:50 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][138:4:1] sensitive_data: sensitive data - U.S. social security numbers without dashes [Classification: Sensitive Data] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.10.1.254:39180 -> 56.164.27.51:80
3 --> ids-01p --> 23:51 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][138:4:1] sensitive_data: sensitive data - U.S. social security numbers without dashes [Classification: Sensitive Data] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.10.52.97:53967 -> 173.194.37.97:80
4 --> ids-01p --> 23:51 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][119:15:1] http_inspect: OVERSIZE REQUEST-URI DIRECTORY [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.190.1.254:57265 -> 34.44.17.21:80
5 --> ids-01p --> 23:51 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][119:15:1] http_inspect: OVERSIZE REQUEST-URI DIRECTORY [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.190.1.254:41960 -> 34.44.17.29:80
--------------------- 6 -------------------
0 --> ids-01p --> 23:48 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][138:4:1] sensitive_data: sensitive data - U.S. social security numbers without dashes [Classification: Sensitive Data] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.190.97.42:3065 -> 43.87.66.38:80
Perl exited with active threads:
        1 running and unjoined
        0 finished and unjoined
        0 running and detached
1 --> ids-01p --> 23:50 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][138:4:1] sensitive_data: sensitive data - U.S. social security numbers without dashes [Classification: Sensitive Data] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.190.1.254:26616 -> 43.67.61.202:80
```

**O/P when as run without a thread:**

```
0 --> ids-01p --> 36:48 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][138:4:1] sensitive_data: sensitive data - U.S. social security numbers without dashes [Classification: Sensitive Data] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.10.1.254:34053 -> 69.164.26.77:80
1 --> ids-01p --> 36:50 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][138:4:1] sensitive_data: sensitive data - U.S. social security numbers without dashes [Classification: Sensitive Data] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.1.65.51:57977 -> 216.137.41.5:80
2 --> ids-01p --> 36:53 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][128:4:1] ssh: Protocol mismatch [Classification: Detection of a Non-Standard Protocol or Event] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.10.241.46:11120 -> 10.10.125.227:22
3 --> ids-01p --> 36:54 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][128:4:1] ssh: Protocol mismatch [Classification: Detection of a Non-Standard Protocol or Event] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.10.241.46:11122 -> 10.1.125.225:22
4 --> ids-01p --> 36:54 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][138:4:1] sensitive_data: sensitive data - U.S. social security numbers without dashes [Classification: Sensitive Data] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.1.118.96:61686 -> 50.19.254.195:80
5 --> ids-01p --> 36:54 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][138:4:1] sensitive_data: sensitive data - U.S. social security numbers without dashes [Classification: Sensitive Data] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.1.1.254:29437 -> 184.73.178.248:80
--------------------- 7 -------------------
0 --> ids-01p --> 36:48 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][138:4:1] sensitive_data: sensitive data - U.S. social security numbers without dashes [Classification: Sensitive Data] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.10.1.254:34053 -> 69.164.26.77:80
1 --> ids-01p --> 36:50 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][138:4:1] sensitive_data: sensitive data - U.S. social security numbers without dashes [Classification: Sensitive Data] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.1.65.51:57977 -> 216.137.41.5:80
2 --> ids-01p --> 36:53 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][128:4:1] ssh: Protocol mismatch [Classification: Detection of a Non-Standard Protocol or Event] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.10.241.46:11120 -> 10.10.125.227:22
3 --> ids-01p --> 36:54 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][128:4:1] ssh: Protocol mismatch [Classification: Detection of a Non-Standard Protocol or Event] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.10.241.46:11122 -> 10.1.125.225:22
4 --> ids-01p --> 36:54 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][138:4:1] sensitive_data: sensitive data - U.S. social security numbers without dashes [Classification: Sensitive Data] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.1.118.96:61686 -> 50.19.254.195:80
5 --> ids-01p --> 36:54 IDS01 SFIMS: [FLIDS][Enterprise][138:4:1] sensitive_data: sensitive data - U.S. social security numbers without dashes [Classification: Sensitive Data] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 10.1.1.254:29437 -> 184.73.178.248:80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use thread join to wait for the thread to finish its job ($thr->join()), thats the reason its complaining about unjoined threads:  *1 running and unjoined*

Comment: Another thing, since using thread join(); the loop has to wait for the thread to finish, and hence it cannot create a new thread, is that right?

Comment: instead of Scalar $thr, use hash and store the threads as keys in the hash, you can than wait outside the for loop for each keys. example code:  my %threads ; $threads{$i} = threads->create('logsys',@set); $i++ ;  then outside the for loop you wait for each keys of %threads